# Can I limit the number of hosts on a subnet to a specific number?

Tags: routing, ip

Is it possible to limit the number of hosts on a network / subnet to a specific number like 237,17 or 20?

I've tried to read up on using subnet-masks, but with these trailing 1's and 0's it seems that i can only limit the number of hosts to   hosts=(2^n)-2 where n = number of 0's and the -2 stands for the broadcast address and the gateway.

Comment: if you count the gateway it's actually (2^n)-3, you forgot the network address.

Comment: A gateway is just another host on the network. The concept of a gateway is a host concept, not a network concept.

Comment: @JFL: Thanks for noticing, i was not correct in my description. After reading up i see i should have called it the subnet ID or network address

Comment: @RonMaupin: :) Thanks for clarifying that also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said you cannot have a network that has a custom number of available IP addresses.

There may be various way to effectively limit the number of possible hosts on the networks but it greatly depends of you network topology / equipment / configuration.

You could limit if physically for wired networks, but I guess in most case this is not very practical.

Maybe the more practical / secure way is to implement access control lists (firewall rules) on the router that will drop the traffic for unwanted IP addresses for each network.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. It depends greatly on your network setup. Our SDN setup lets me impose a hard limit at the DHCP source, but we don't use that feature. On a standard cisco, juniper, or procurve deploment, I don't know of a way to limit the number of hosts. I also can't think of a use case for limiting the number of hosts. Wouldn't you instead want to Permit only certain hosts? That would be much safer.

Answer (score 0):

Limit the DHCP pool for the subnet and write an ACL to block the addresses not in the pool.

Comment: You should improve your answer by explaining.

Answer (score 0):

In the concept of subnetnetting. No specific number of hosts cannot be customised for limiting    . Any ways your requirement can be accomplished in another way .

Configure DHCP scope for each subnet in layer3 device or in server it's depends upon your requirements

**If your network is static  IP address environment**

Then  exclude ip address from DHCP pool and allocated then manually to systems

Assuming your  hosts machines are limited to 50

Assuming your network subnet is 192.168.1.0/24

`Router(config)# ip DHCP excluded adddress 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.254

**If your network is DHCP environment**

Then exclude ip address from DHCP pool and make sure only 50 IP  address are remaining to allocate for 50 host from this DHCP pool .